# Compare forecast interval between ARIMA and ARIMA/GARCH

Tags: time-series, arima, heteroscedasticity, garch, prediction-interval

I tried to compute parameters of ARIMA/GARCH in two step. The first one is to build ARIMA and then fit GARCH using iid Gaussian MLE estimation. The second one is to construct ARIMA/GARCH simultaneously based on conditional Gaussian MLE. When I used this two methods to model the log return of a stock, prediction intervals of two method is different. For separate estimation, the interval is wider than interval of ARIMA. However for consist estimation, it is narrower than that of ARIMA. There are papers show variation in variance would cause narrower estimation in OLS, since it makes sense to display a wider interval for ARIMA/GARCH. But why it is narrower for consist estimation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about *confidence intervals* for model parameters or *forecast intervals* (*prediction intervals*)? (These are different things.) If the latter, please change the tag from `confidence-interval` to `prediction-interval`. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is the prediction

Comment: I think there is no general answer to the question. The difference between the fitted forecast intervals depends on how bad is two-stage estimation as compared to simulataneous estimation, but there is no way of saying which ones should be wider. By the way, ARIMA cannot be estimated by OLS unless the MA part is nonexistent. Normally, maximum likelihood estimation would be used for both ARIMA and ARIMA-GARCH.